# Android Studio and Intellij

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-home

I have Android studio installed with the environment variable JAVA_HOME set appropriately for AS. This is incompatible with the installation (64bit) Windows 10 for IntelliJ. How do I fix this so that I have both IDEs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `incompatible`: do you mean AS is 32bit and IntelliJ 64 bit, or... ?

Comment: Fixed. The problem  was the Java, jdk and jre became out of sync with respect to versions. Reinstalling the Java package from scratch and resetting the JAVA_HOME to point to the new JDK fixed things.